# Issue with Reverse Link List - Leetcode Problem NoneType Error

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am attempting to reverse a link list as per this leetcode problem: [ReverseLL](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list/description/)

My code:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution(object):
    def reverseList(self, head):
        """
        :type head: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        cur = head
        nxt = cur.next
        while nxt != None:
            temp = nxt.next
            nxt.next = cur
            cur = nxt
            nxt = temp
        
        head.next = None
        head = cur
        return head
```

However, I am getting an attribute error in the line:

```
    nxt = cur.next
```

Error message: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'`

But I'm not too sure why cur is a noneType when I have assigned it to be head?

Comment: _why cur is a noneType when I have assigned it to be head_ That is the case at the beginning of the loop.  Presumably the error does not happen immediately, but only after several loop iterations, at which time `cur` is no longer equal to `head`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, you are trying to access the `next` attribute of `cur` immediately after initializing it to `head`, without first checking if `head` is `None`. So any input to `reverseList` if empty, will result in `Attribute error` in your case.

You can check for the case where `head` is `None` before the while loop.

```
if head is None:
  return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Because head also can be None, before assignment do

```
if head is None:
    return head
```